# liferay6.2 GENERATING MODEL, SERVICE, AND PERSISTENCE LAYERS failed

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm learning liferay6.2, and I'm now reading chapter "USING SERVICE BUILDER TO GENERATE A PERSISTENCE FRAMEWORK" which url is

```
https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/using-service-builder-to-generate-a-persistence-fr
```

I have no problem about "CREATING A SERVICE.XML FILE", "Understanding Liferay Portal Concepts". However, when I read "GENERATING MODEL, SERVICE, AND PERSISTENCE LAYERS" and press the "Build Services button", then liferay generate a lot of error files for me.

[After press "Build Services button"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glqxo.png)

I search this problem on google, and I find some person have discussed it one year ago.

```
https://web.liferay.com/zh/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/52930858
```

In that page, one person said this problem can only be solved by jdk1.7 32bit. I don't understand why I have to use out-time technology in order to solve this problem.

Can anyone use jdk1.8 64bit to solve this problem?

Comment: What's the problem? Write down a stack trace please

Comment: Have you tried to switch to jdk1.7? It worked? By the way, you are already using an out-time tecnology, infact the last version of Liferay is 7.

Comment: I have not try jdk1.7 yet. Because jdk1.7 is not available in oracle website now.

Comment: Did you try jdk 1.8 32 bit too?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use jdk 1.7 and link it to your project in order to generate your service. Change your environment variable and right click on the project in eclipse and use jdk from java

Documentacion version 6.2: https://web.liferay.com/documents/14/21598941/Liferay+Portal+6.2+EE+Compatibility+Matrix.pdf

Liferay 7 still has a long way to go....